# Red Eagle's Fury keeps vanishing on me

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, ps3

I have reloaded from saves three times now, but the same thing happens. I currently have Red Eagle's Fury equipped, but as soon as I fast travel anywhere it just ups and disappears from my inventory. Could I somehow have dropped it?

Though all that seems to trigger it is fast travelling, and whenever I draw my weapon after, In the hand where Red eagle used to be, an arrow is now equipped.

i'm playing on the PS3, so unfortunately console commands won't help.

Also, I had the glitch earlier where I had two at one point and I managed to sell one, could this be the glitch resolving itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're carrying the "ghost" of a weapon that was bugged in the inventory. If the merchant you sold the real one to didn't respawn, you should be able to retrieve it from him, if not, you're out of luck. Red Eagle's weapons are pretty average for uniques though, don't worry about it too much.